# Mutual inductance

Tags: mutual-inductance

I am confused about derivation of the next formula 
[image]

The question is about Cm term.

We have coupled inductors.

[image]

The voltage across first coil is

[image]

And I am ok with it. I understand it.

I know that current I1 causes a flux in the magnetic core

[image]

Where c is

[image]

But I cannot understand the first formula. How do we get Cm term?

I thought there would must be

[image]

My misunderstanding does not relate to the nature of Cm or C1 terms. I do not understand how do we get it mathematically.

Comment: I'm assuming that \$c\$ is the equivalent of \$\lambda\$ in some sources, which indicates the flux linkage between the coils. Am I correct? While \$v,i,N,\$ and \$\phi\$ are very common nomenclature for mutual inductance, \$c\$ and \$\theta\$ are not so you may have to explain what that those indicate.

Comment: c is a constant that depends on the magnetic properties and geometry of the core. I have added this n my question just now

Comment: By θ I mean ϕ. It is my error

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what text your pulling this from, but just looking at the first equation you have:

$$V_2 = C_MN_1N_2\frac{di_1}{dt}= M\frac{di_1}{dt}$$

which means that from the equations listed above at the time of writing:

$$M=C_MN_1N_2$$

In other literature (such as this article on [mutual inductance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leakage_inductance) or my [CRC book](https://www.crcpress.com/Fundamentals-of-Circuits-and-Filters/Chen/p/book/9781420058871)) M is the mutual inductance ratio k is the coupling factor which describes the leakage out of each inductor (not all of the magnetic flux lines flow through the other side of the transformer)

$$M=k\sqrt{L_1L_2}$$

or

$$M=\sqrt{k_1L_1k_2L_2}$$

In a problem k or C_M are usually given to you, or they come from another leakage parameter because inductors are not perfect. For iedal transformers, these parameters are 1. For non ideal transformers, between 1 and 0

Comment: Yes. But why Cm and not C1? It was my question. I wrote that my question does not relate to the nature or meaning of C. How did they get Cm instead of C1. That is the question

Comment: It is from my book Richard Dorf Introduction to electric circuits 9th edition. Richard Dorf is also the series editor of your CRC book.

Comment: You can see that in the equations above with the k values, k is the leakage parameter for both, k1 and k2 apply to reach inductor individually. For Cm, you'll have a parameter for both and a C1 and C2 for each of the individual inductors

Comment: You also said I do not understand how to get "it" what it are you referring to, in cases like this it helps to be specific

Comment: C is permeance. By "it" I mean " how do we get cm term in the equation for V2 (voltage at the second coil)". Just substitute the formula for ϕ in the V2's equatuon and you will get the same result. I acked about mathematical deriveation. Read my question simply

Comment: C is permeance. By "it" I mean " how do we get cm term in the equation for V2 (voltage at the second coil)". Just substitute the formula for ϕ in the V2's equatuon and you will get the same result. I acked about mathematical deriveation. Read my question simply